# jQuery self-processing AJAX request with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a working php login form that I am now trying to process with jquery ajax request in the same page, but upon submitting the form with correct credentials, i still receive "invalid login" message.

Little new to jquery and ajax but my code is below. Any help with a little explanation so i can learn and understand rather than copying greatly appreciated thanks!

The following are on the same page in this order.

### PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if( $num_row >=1 ) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();

    } else {
        echo "Invalid login. Please try again.";
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#login").click(function() {

    var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        is_ajax: 1
    };       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: location.href,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response == 'success')
                $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                });
            else
                $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");   
        }
    });       
    return false;
});   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Login Form</h1>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

      <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Submit" />
  </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Don't forget to sanitize your input.** http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't actually told PHP to output anything, so obviously, the page that made the AJAX call will be receiving nothing upon a sucessful login, and `nothing != 'success'`, so that's why it's showing the error page.

You should have echoed out the `'success'` string when the log in was successful.

```
...
if( $num_row >=1 )
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit('success');
}
else
{
    exit('Invalid login. Please try again.');
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call ajax in jQuery, you have the option of returning the response on success. In this case you are checking via jQuery whether `response == 'success'`. In your PHP, you never output `'success'` - so it will always return false.

Try this:

```
if( $num_row >=1 )
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
    echo "success";
    exit();
}
else
{
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the resopnse! I tried modifying my code with your reply but still does not function. I'm a little confused in understanding your comment, could your provide further explanation? Thank you!!!